# Scrollable div is missing scrollbar on mobile device

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile, scrollbar

I have a div with overflow scroll. The scrollbar appears and works fine in the desktop browser, in all responsive views in the browser, on Browserstack and in X-code simulator. But the scrollbar is missing when I view the page on my mobile device in iOS Safari. Is there some css to ensure the scrollbar will be visible on mobile devices?

Here's what I have so far...

The markup:
`<div class="scrollable">...</div>`

The css:

```
.scrollable {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbars seem to be hidden automatically in the latest versions of iOS. Since you are using Browserstack the scrollbar should appear fine when testing on an Android device.

If l am not mistaken the browsers in iOS should display the scrollbar when the div content is scrolled and then it will autohide it again. The iOS user can change a setting that disables the scrollbar autohide "feature".

There isn't a .css-only solution as far as l know. If you want a carousel-like solution it can be achieved via .css only by offsetting the items in the parent element so that one element of the overflowed content is partially visible signalling to the user that is scrollable content in the parent div. You can make the parent snap to the start or end of the children elements via .css

Another solution would be using something like:

1. [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)
2. [slick slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

These are using jquery but should offer a more consistent experience than a pure .css solution.